# Group by first two numbers in a field and give it a name with totals in SSRS/Expression. 2102 & 2104 would be 2100 Group

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, reporting-services, expression

I would like to group by the first two numbers, rename it, and then do sub totals along with grand totals.

so for example i have:

```
2102 - 5
2104 - 10
2205 - 7
2209 - 11
```

it would look like this in the end:

```
2102 - 5
2104 - 10
2100 Group Total: 15

2205 - 7
2209 - 11
2200 Group Total: 18

     Grand Total: 33
```

I know I can right click on the 4 digit code and Add Group - Parent Group -> but I am lost on the expression. I have tried writing my own but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do is create a **Calculated Field** to get the desired *xx00* field, then use this as your grouping item in the report.

Say I have data like this:

[image]

I have added a Calculated Field called `Group` with an expression:

```
=Left(CStr(Fields!Number1.Value), 2) & "00"
```

[image]

You could use any number of expressions here - I just chose this one as you don't specify the data types and this should be pretty safe for most types.

From here, just set up a standard Tablix grouped on the new field:

[image]

[image]

Works OK for me:

[image]

**Edit after comment**

To apply an arbitrary value to the different groupings, you could add a Calculated Field (say `TeamGroup`) with a `Switch` expression, something like:

```
=Switch(Left(CStr(Fields!Number1.Value), 2) = "20", "Team1"
  , Left(CStr(Fields!Number1.Value), 2) = "21", "Team2"
  , Left(CStr(Fields!Number1.Value), 2) = "22", "Team3")
```

You could add more groupings as required. You could then use it exactly the same way as above, i.e. as the Group expression or the summary label textbox, something like:

```
=Fields!TeamGroup.Value & " Group Total:"
```

Comment: sweet! finally rebuilt what you did and got that part working.

Comment: anyway to set it where 2100 would equal Group Name that is different from 2200? so instead of 2100 Group Total it would be Team 1 Group Total etc ...

Comment: I've added a few thoughts; please see it above.

Comment: yeah i went this route with the switch statement:
    =Switch(Fields!group.Value = 5100,"Overhead Pool         Total",Fields!group.Value = 5200,"Site Control Total",Fields!group.Value = 5300,"Resource Assessment Total")

Comment: Ian - thanks again.

quick question, how would i group or add a range of groups? for example i have groups: 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600 etc ... and i wanted the total of just 2100, 2200, and 2300 and call it a category total.

possibly add another group and put filters?